# How to move object across rendered image but do not change rotation from camera's view

Tags: python, scripting, blender-internal-render-engine

I am trying to write a blender script that moves an object in across a rendered image. The object will appear to rotate, but is it possible to make the object appear the same even moving it across the image? This explanation may be bad, so I attached some images.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The first image is the "canonical" view. The second image is what happens if I move the object to the left. The last image is a poorly edited image of what I want the output to be. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the assumption the model you're moving across is 3D mesh then 'perspective rotation' would certainly occur.  You'd even get this effect, although much less, if the object was a flat plane textured with a pic.

The answer would be to get the camera itself into "Ortho" mode. (as distinct from the viewport's Ortho mode)

The two videos show the difference when the camera is set to Perspective and Ortho View.  I am assuming that Python would allow the camera to be set to Ortho independently.

[image] . [image]

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: That's good to hear!  :)